# How to redirect to previous page in PHP without http_refferer

Tags: php

I want to redirect to the preverious page. I don't want to use the PHP $_SERVER['http_reffer']

I'm using PHP friendly URLs if it is important. My actual solution is:

```php
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This doesn't work and i get this Message in Firefox: 'The page isn't redirecting properly'

Is there any solution?

Comment: *I don't want to use the PHP $_SERVER['http_reffer']*.  Why not?  What if that's what http_refer is designed for?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger I don't want to use this tag, because this isn't always used. For example if I navigate to a page manually.

Comment: @AlexBarker okay! Can you please answer this question so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: you can place a previous page session variable to do something like that, for a user that is logged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to redirect to the same location you are currently at, which intern redirects again and again. You must either use http_reffer or you need to track the previous page loaded for the user and store it somewhere like the session. You will need a default location to redirect to in either case as there is no guarantee it will be set.

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['last_location'] = "https://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}";
    session_write_close();
```

```
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["last_location"])) {
        header("Location: {$_SESSION["last_location"]}");
    } else {
        header("Location: {$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple steps:

1. Enable the `HTTP_REFERER` header
2. Redirect with `header()` using the `HTTP_REFERER`.

Make sure it's possible to use the `HTTP_REFERER`.  If you don't have this set, you won't be able to see `HTTP_REFERER` in your `$_SESSION` data...

```
ini_set('session.referer_check', 'TRUE');
```

Then simply redirect to it with the `$_SERVER` variable using [**header()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)...

```
header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], TRUE, 307);
```

- `TRUE`: Turn on `$replace`, to replace a previous header sent, this is the default parameter.
- `307`: Temporary Redirect, thte HTTP Code.

It is always good practice to set the [**HTTP Response Code.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)  307 is the response code, which means temporary redirect.  For simply returning to the previous page, that seems appropriate.  (But if you are doing something more complicated, you may want something else, though, like 301: Moved Permanently, or 308: Permanent Redirect.)